# Как узнать/сохранить адрес с которого вернулись назад?

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Есть текущий адрес `/url1`. Когда жмем "назад", то перескакиваем на `/`, так-как я, изначально, пришел с `/`, все правильно.

Как мне отследить этот самый `/url1`, когда перескакивает на `/`?
То есть нужно после `popstate`, знать предыдущий адрес.
Есть-ли вообще возможность узнать откуда ушли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить через `localStorage` и через `cookie` тоже работает.
Пришлось решать костылем с проверкой на записываемое значение.